# eclipseで作成したファイルをcmdで実行

Tags: java, eclipse, コマンドプロンプト

参考書では `javac Main.java Hero.java` でコンパイルすると書いてあったのですが
ユーザー環境変数に`CLASSPATH`(`C:¥work`)を登録しても

> メイン・クラスMain.javaを検出できませんでした。

と表示され実行できません.
ワークスペースは`C:¥workd`に設定しています.
そこで、`java -cp bin Main` と `java Main` と `cd \work\Main.java\bin\`を試してみても実行できませんでした
`cd ¥work` してから上のコードをうってもダメでした.
どうしたらecliipseで作成したファイルをcmdで実行できるのでしょうか.

#### 追記

`Main.java` は `Rpg1`, `Hero.java` は `Rpg2` というパッケージ宣言をしています。eclipse の ワークスペースは `C:¥work`で , `Main.java` は `C:¥work\Main.java\bin`というフォルダに存在しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

とりあえず以下の点を確認してみてください。

- Main.java にパッケージ名を指定していますか？それとも無名パッケージでしょうか？
  Main.java の最初の方に package 宣言があるか確認してください。
- clipse のワークスペースは以下のどちらでしょうか？

  - C:¥work
  - C:¥workd
- Main.java というファイルはどのフォルダに存在していますか？

  - C:¥work\Main.java
  - C:¥workd\Main.java
  - C:¥workd\<どこかののサブフォルダ>/Main.java
  - その他

いずれにしても Main.java を示さないと適切な回答は得られないと思います。